# Bungled up home screen (Desktop)

Tags: screen, home-directory

I was wondering if anyone has seen this and have a solution without a reinstall?[home path folders and such on home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cLU4.jpg)
[image: desktop view of icons]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question to show which version of Ubuntu you have installed. Do your display settings (Start Menu >> Display) match your screen?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, then log out and back in.

The file `user-dirs.dirs` is found in the hidden folder `.config` in you home directory. Enable "Show hidden files" in the file manager to see that directory, and delete the file. Instead, you can open a terminal and use the command `rm ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to delete the file.

When, after logging out, you log back in, that file will be recreated with the system defaults, and your desktop folders again will be only these in the "Desktop" folder.